# Performance of multiple joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, performance, join

Given the following tables :

**actions**

```
 - id - UNSIGNED INT - PRIMARY KEY
 - name - VARCHAR(50)
 - user1_id - UNSIGNED INT - INDEX
 - user2_id - UNSIGNED INT - INDEX
 - user3_id - UNSIGNED INT - INDEX
```

(I made this short for the example but there are actually 9 users)

**users**

```
 - id - UNSIGNED INT - PRIMARY KEY
 - name - VARCHAR(50)
```

I want to display a list of actions with the name of each of the users (note : an action does not always have all its users defined)

The only solution I can come up with is an horrible query with one left join for each user :

```
SELECT name, user1.name AS name1, user2.name AS name2, user3.name AS name3
FROM actions
LEFT JOIN users AS user1 ON user1.id = actions.user1_id
LEFT JOIN users AS user2 ON user2.id = actions.user2_id
LEFT JOIN users AS user3 ON user3.id = actions.user3_id
```

The actual query has 9 left joins for the 9 users (+ 2 inner joins to recover some other stuff about the action)

This works, but there must be a more performant solution. How bad is this one ? Is there a difference (in terms of performance) between 9 joins on the same tables and 9 joins on 9 similar tables ?

Comment: Appropriately indexed, this query will be fine.

Comment: The better solution would be to redesign your database and have another table linking actions to user ids. This would also have the advantage of being more easily expanded when an action required more than 9 users.

Comment: That would also add joins to more simple queries that just need to recover IDs and not names (which is why it's usually a bad idea to create a link table for 1-n relations). But in that case, that's probably worth it. Thank you

Comment: A join on an indexed id should be very fast

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this will get you similar result set, if flipped around:

```
SELECT a.name, u.name
FROM actions a
CROSS JOIN users u
```

Comment: Did you really mean _cross_?

Comment: yea, I guess the result set he was looking for just sounded like the cross product of the two sets to me.